# I need a max-margin CSS property, but it doesn't exist. How could I fake it?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a simple page with the following characteristics:

1. Its body must be at least 60em wide.
2. Its left and right margins must be equally wide and at most 3em wide.
3. When the browser window is resized, the document's margins should be resized so that the browser window's horizontal scrollbar covers the least wide possible range.

Transforming these requirements into a linear programming problem, we get:

```
DEFINITIONS:
BRWS = (width of the browser window, not a variable)
BODY = (width of the document's body)
LRMG = (width of the document's left and right margins)
HSCR = (range of the browser window's horizontal scroll bar)

OBJECTIVE:
MIN HSCR   /* Third requirement */

CONSTRAINTS:
HSCR = BODY + 2*LRMG - BRWS  /* From the definition of how a browser's
                              * horizontal scrollbar works. */
BODY >= 60  /* First requirement */
LRMG <= 3   /* Second requirement */
LRMG >= 0   /* Physical constraint, margins cannot be negative */
HSCR >= 0   /* Physical constraint, scroll bars cannot have negative ranges */
```

Solving this linear program, we get:

```
BODY = (BRWS <= 66) ? 60 : (BRWS - 6)
HSCR = (BRWS >= 60) ?  0 : (60 - BRWS)
LRMG = (BRWS + HSCR - BODY) / 2
```

(Sorry for the boring math, but I am not confident that the original explanation in English was clear enough.)

---

Now back to the actual page. After googling to find what I could do with CSS, I managed to implement the first two requirements using the following code:

```
body {
  min-width: 60em; /* First requirement */
}

/* The document's body has only two children, both of which are divs. */
body > div {
  margin: 0 3em;    /* Second requirement, but in a way that makes */
  max-width: 100%;  /* it impossible to satisfy the third one. */
}
```

If CSS had a `max-margin` property, satisfying all requirements would be easy:

```
body > div {
  max-margin: 0 3em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

But, of course, `max-margin` does not exist. How could I fake it?

Comment: javascript out of the question?

Comment: Hope not, because that's the only way he's going to get it done ;)

Comment: Are you trying to create a centred layout? i.e. a div that is fixed width wise, but stays in the centre even when the browser is resized?

Comment: @Niklas: Yes. I know how to do this with JavaScript, but this is something JavaScript should not be required for.

Comment: @Darknight: I already have a centered layout. What I want is that _both_ the document's body and the document's margins be resized in an sensible way.

Comment: do you have a link to an demo/example of the page, because I'm still not clear on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If I am reding this corectly he is trying to create a centered layout where the content's width is variable, but a minimum of 60em. aditionally the content should have a margin of 3em that is to shrink if the browser window is not wide enough.

Comment: @skajfes: Exactly! Why couldn't I say it that way?

Comment: probably because you didn't have enough to drink :)

Comment: Can you use css3 media queries?

Comment: @skajfes: Also probably because I am too mathematically-inclined for my own good.

Comment: @Chris J. Lee: What are CSS3 media queries? :-o

Comment: ok that makes a lot more sense now. So when the user expands the browser, are you saying in effect the central div will expand (but keep 3em margins either side)? And as the browser is reduced (width wise), the central div should also shrink BUT not **less** then 60em. And it can even eat into the 3em margins in order to attempt to maintain the minimum 60em?

Comment: @Eduardo: I understand you completly because I am also like that. I've also noticed that I can express myself more clearly to humans when I have a couple of beers in me (disclaimer: I am not advocating drinking, I am just stating an observation)

Comment: Dammit, I wish I could downvote my own question, because this is totally stupid.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Spacer divs on either side of the content divs.  Those are your margins.  Set their max width using the max-width property.

Comment: <s>This looks ugly, but let's see.</s> Yep, it works. Thanks.

Comment: Just read the comments.  Sorry... @media query would give you the browser width and you could say if the browser width is less than the min width (if media queries don't work with ems - not sure - then 960 px is 60em in most browsers) then make the margin 0.

Comment: Spacer divs are a technique from like five years ago.  I hate them, but if you gotta you gotta.

Comment: You could use the :before and :after pseudo classes to generate ghost spacer divs that don't actually appear in your markup.

Comment: floating spacer divs work, but won't it stop you from clearing floats inside your page? Since the cleared content will also clear the floating spacer divs and appear below the bottom of your page.

Comment: ^^ This is nice.. :-)

Comment: What's a spacer div? Could we see a code example here? Thanks.

Comment: While this seems like a work-around, it's really the best solution given that max-margin should be feature in CSS3

Answer (score 19):

To mimic a variable-width left margin:

```
.div-class {
    display: inline-block;
}
.div-class:before {
    content: '';
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is a beautiful hack.

Comment: Very elegant to achieve this with pure CSS without the need to create auxillary HTML DIV elements.

Answer (score 15):

For pure CSS that works in any scenario:

1. use *@media* to create a break point.
2. Set a *max-width* rule below a certain size using responsive width measurements such as an *em* or *%* and over that size use static widths such as *px*.

You'll just need to do the math to figure out the static sizes at the break point to make sure it scales fluidly.

**Sample Code:**

```
.my_class {
   margin: 0px 10%;
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   .my_class { 
      margin: 0px 10px;
   } 
}
```

This will make `.my_class` follow both:

- The `margin: 0px 10%;` at over a screen width of *480px*
- The `margin: 0px 10px;` at under *480px*.

Comment: This is not only better because it works, but because it actually works! With an extra `<div>` on the left (or right) you have to use `float: left` or equivalent and you cannot use a `width: 100%` for the inner `<div>` so you either have to add a JavaScript or use your solution which is just perfect!

Answer (score 8):

For anyone coming to this post in 2021. I would like to point you to the answer given in this post: [Can we define min-margin and max-margin, max-padding and min-padding in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078957/can-we-define-min-margin-and-max-margin-max-padding-and-min-padding-in-css).

TLDR: Use css math function `min`

Answer (score 7):

Matthew's answer is the correct one here, but to expand on what he's saying:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="content">Content goes here</div>
<div id="right"></div>
<!-- probably need a cleanup div to fix floats here -->
```

CSS:

```
#left, #right {
    float: left;
    max-width: 3em;
}

#content {
    min-width: 60em;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Easy as that

```
margin-left: min(30%, 150px);
margin-right: min(30%, 150px);
```

[image]

[image]

```css
.margin-flat {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  background: #F6D55C;
}

.margin-max {
  margin-left: min(30%, 150px);
  margin-right: min(30%, 150px);
  background: #3CAEA3;
}

.margin-variable {
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  background: #ED553B;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner margin-variable">margin: 30%</div>
  <div class="inner margin-max">margin: 30%<br/>max-margin: 150px</div>
  <div class="inner margin-flat">margin: 150px</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60em;
}
```

Comment: That should center it (only). – Other “max-margin” seems not possible.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers worked for me 100%.

Best way is to use **CSS `table`** and **`table-cell`**. Supported by all browsers (even IE 8). This handles wrapping way better than `float` or `inline-block` solutions, when the page is too narrow.

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.wrapper > .content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper>
    <div class="content>
        <!-- content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to know you found something that works for you. I stopped getting involved with this CSS madness long ago. :-)

Comment: You can run, but never hide from CSS ;)=

Answer (score 1):

Spacer divs are bad practice. Setup another DIV on top of your DIV on your template with `text-align:right` (if you want to maximize the margin-left) or  `text-align:left` if you want to maximize the margin-right, this will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some very appealing solutions alreaady, but here's a solution that require's relatively little code:

Place the contents of the body in a div inside it, and use `display: flex; justify-content: space-around;`

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

div {
    margin: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 60em;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div>
... contents of the page ...
</div>
</body>
```

The gray background is only to visualize the resulting body.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.labite.com/

Re-size the window to observe the changes to the ui.

The website uses min-width max-width with width:100%

The black frame has max-width which is little wider then the container.

Comment: A little more detail/context/code would be nicer here.