# How does padding percentage work?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='elementContainer'>
        This line should start halfway down the yellow box
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper
{
    position: relative;

    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;

    background: lightyellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.elementContainer
{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;

    padding-top: 50%;

    background: red;
}
```

**Fiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/s2ZXV/

In the example above, `.elementContainer` has a padding-top of `50%`. This should be calculated based on the parent element's (`.wrapper`) height, which means it should come out to `150px`. Instead, it comes out to `200px`. What's going on?

Comment: Apparently it's being calculated as `.elementContainer` `padding-top: 50%`

Comment: ...yeah, that's what I wrote.

Comment: I think you might be misreading the documentation.  The documentation states that percentages are based on the "containing block," not the parent of the containing block.

Comment: In that case, it should only be `100px`, since the containing block is `200px` tall.

Comment: OK, well the documentation also states that it is based on the *width*, which in your case is 400 in `.wrapper`  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982480) for an alternative.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties) explain why.

> `<percentage>`
>   The percentage is calculated with respect to the *width* of the generated box's containing block

50% of 400 is 200.

Comment: width without margin with box-sizing: border-box;