# css/html: padding in % doesn't make sense

Tags: html, css

Consider the following html

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"/>
</div>
```

I've given the parent a height of 100px. The child has a height of 100% and a padding of "10% 0".
In CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#parent {
    height: 100px ;
}
#child {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10% 0;
}
```

Or checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YKvgS/) jsfiddle.
Anyway, from the above I would expect the child div to have a top/bottom border of 10px (10% of 100px). But it is 31.5px. Can someone explain why this happens and how I can achieve what I want ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percentage is width based: If you do this you will get the desired result. Also `<div>` is not self closing.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#parent {
    height: 100px;
    width : 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
#child {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10% 0%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

See related question: [How to set the margin or padding as percentage of height of parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982480/how-to-set-the-margin-or-padding-as-percentage-of-height-or-parent-container)

Comment: ok, thnx. But in my case the width can be anything. I assume that the only solution in my case is using javascript

Comment: Np, yeah I think JavaScript is the solution for now.

Answer (score 5):

Any percentage value will be calculated using the width of the element.

Comment: +1 Agreed. [From MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top): "Percentages refer to the width of the containing block".

Answer (score 2):

The % is based on the width of the element not the height.