# How do I put 'fadein' and 'animate' texts in the middle of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to assign a group of stacking texts in the middle of the page? placing them in the center wasn't too difficult, but the problem was that they are positioned `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`, which I think means they need to be given: `position:absolute`. Furthermore, the `.headline` texts are given `fade-in`(opacity 0 to 100) and `animation` commands. In terms of scaling, the texts are responsive, and get smaller as the window gets smaller. In addition they are assigned their own `z-index`.

In the image below, I have laid out the overall structure I would like to achieve, but I'm experiencing a lot of difficulty doing so because of the text behaviors I want to accomplish.

[image]

For functionality reference, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/99cjp4zh/6/).

Please help me and thank you in advance! Please note that I would prefer to use CSS only since it's a simple function that only occurs once upon page load. However, if this is a issue that only javascript can solve, please let me know :)

```css
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
.fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -moz-animation-name: fade;
    -o-animation-name: fade;
    animation-name: fade;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flowright {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes flowright {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        left: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        left: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flowleft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        right: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        right: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes flowleft {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        right: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        right: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flowup {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes flowup {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flowdown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes flowdown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: -100px;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
.flow {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
}
.right {
    -webkit-animation-name: flowright;
    animation-name: flowright;
}
.left {
    -webkit-animation-name: flowleft;
    animation-name: flowleft;
}
.up {
    -webkit-animation-name: flowup;
    animation-name: flowup;
}
.down {
    -webkit-animation-name: flowdown;
    animation-name: flowdown;
}
.sequence01 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.sequence02 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.sequence03 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.sequence04 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
/* Headline Typography */
.headline {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
}
/* Rows */
 .row01, .row02, .row03 {
    clear: both;
}
.row01 {
    left:20%;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.row02 {
    right:10%;
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.row03 {
    left:10%;
    top: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
/* General Structure */
 body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.pagewrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 48em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff6d6;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="pagewrap">
        <div class="headline">
            <div class="row01 flow left sequence01">ROW 01</div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row02 flow right sequence02">ROW 02</div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row03 flow up sequence03">ROW 03</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/99cjp4zh/7/**

Comment: Hi @adeneo not sure what changes you have made

Comment: I moved the  elements like in your image, isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not really seeing a difference. The texts are still stacked on top of the page, the animations (flow) are not responding... Is the url that you provided correct?

Comment: I probably misunderstood, I just moved the text to match the image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/99cjp4zh/8/

Comment: that looks great! however, when loading the page, the texts respond to the other text animations. Is there a way the text can maintain its position? Thank you in advance for all the help :)

EDIT: Nevermind, resolved!

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by adeneo in the comments may work perfectly fine, but since your layout is strictly vertical, why not just use a `block` layout instead of `inline-block` or `float`s?

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/t1xLfLyu/1/)**.

You mention a "padding" percentage between the rows as well. Note that `margin` and `padding` css attributes as percentages will key off of the **`width`** not the **`height`**. I placed divs to solve that, but **[there are other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982480/how-to-set-the-margin-or-padding-as-percentage-of-height-or-parent-container)**.

### Edit

If the `headline` needs to be vertically centered to the page, here's a nifty way to do it using the "ghost element technique":

```
/* Headline Typography */
 .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
 
/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

.headline {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1xLfLyu/3/)**

I learned of it **[here](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)**.

Comment: Hi @NanoWizard, the website is actually not strictly vertical—thats why i set the page-wrap to a height of 100% and a width of 80%. adeneo's method works for me because it responds to the windows top and bottom point, thus centering it in the middle. However, your second suggestion was interesting — what a good idea— to use the padding to fill the remaining vertical space. I'll give that a try. 

Thanks! :)