# Why div percentage margin are incorrect?

Tags: html, css

I am currently having an issue where the percentages I am using for a child div, in relation to the parent div, do not seem to be working.

```
<div id="NavBar">
    <div class="Button"></div>
    <div class="Button"></div>
    <div class="Button"></div>
    <div class="Button"></div>
    <div class="Button"></div>
</div>

#NavBar {
    Height:10vh;
    Width:100%;
    background-color:gray;
    float:left;
    position:relative;

.Button {
    Height:90%;
    Width:10%;
    margin-left:8.5%;
    margin-top:5%;
    background-color:Black;
    float:left;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7duea0ou/

5% of the parent div is certainly not the entire height of it and I am not sure what is causing this issue.

How do I make it so that the margin is only 5% of the parent div?

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: `%` for `height` refers to the `width` of the parent element, not its `height`, as unintuitive as that may seem.

Comment: Wait, really? Why is it designed that way?

Comment: This is incorrect. This behaviour is applicable to margin and padding. Percentages on height will use the height of the parent element as a reference, as expected (if a height has been defined).

Comment: But I have defined a height and it has used 5% of the whole screen and not 5% of the parent height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

% values used in margin refers to parent `width` and **not** `height` even for margin-top and margin-bottom. As you can read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#margin-properties):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for
>   'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's
>   width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined
>   in CSS 2.1.

So instead of using % you may consider doing some calculation and using variables.

Here is an example:

```css
:root {
  --main-height: 10vh; /*we define the height of the navbar*/
}

#NavBar {
  height: var(--main-height);
  Width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.Button {
  height: 90%;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 8.5%;
  margin-top: calc((var(--main-height) * 5) / 100); /* we take 5% of the height*/
  background-color: Black;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
</div>
```

By the way your code can be simplified using flex and without setting margin values:

```css
#NavBar {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.Button {
  height: 90%;
  flex-basis: 10%;
  background-color: Black;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
</div>
```

---

Here is a similar question where you can find more ways:

[How to set the margin or padding as percentage of height of parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982480/how-to-set-the-margin-or-padding-as-percentage-of-height-of-parent-container)

Answer (score 0):

`margin` relates to the width of the parent element, no matter the margin you define (left/right or top/bottom).