# Can you set horizontal padding relatively to the element's height in CSS?

Tags: css, layout, padding

When you use `%` unit on `padding` values in CSS, it's relative to the width of that element. Can you somehow set **vertical** padding (`padding-left`, `padding-right`) values relatively to the **height** of that element?

Comment: share you use case. The answer to your question is No but probably your are tackling the problem the wrong way and there is another solution

Comment: I shared my use case with you yesterday in the chat to the previous question you answered to me. I sent you a pen demonstrating the problem.

Comment: but you have asked a new question so you need to add more detail. No one will know that there is a chat somewhere describing your issue and I still didn't find the time to check your messages.

Comment: About this question: This is a general questions and I meant it like that. You mentioned the answer to the general question is "No". Post the answer and I'll accept it. I can post my specific question separately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the margin or padding as percentage of height of parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982480/how-to-set-the-margin-or-padding-as-percentage-of-height-of-parent-container)

Answer (score 0):

At this link (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) you can read:

> All the padding properties can have the following values:
>
> - length - specifies a padding in px, pt, cm, etc.
> - % - specifies a padding in % of the width of the containing element
> - inherit - specifies that the padding should be inherited from the parent element

So **CSS properties will not do this** for you, but you can achieve this in many ways.

For example this one:

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 500px;
    background: Red;
    color: white;
}

.padding {
    height: 20%;
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.content {
    padding: 0 5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="padding"></div>
    <div class="content">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="padding"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As for cases implementing capsule-shaped InputField, you can use `calc()` in css to hack the case like this:

```css
#input-field {
  --padding: 10px;
  padding: var(--padding) calc(.5rem + var(--padding));
  border-radius: 100vw; /* big enough to be super round */

  border: 1px solid #f6c;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-field" placeholder="imma the text!"/>
```

The `.5rem` represents one half of text height, and `var(--padding)` is just a CSS variable for vertical padding!